# Matplotlib time course standard error

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, standard-error

Is there any default way in matplotlib to get standard errors for time course plots?

By this I mean those low-alpha thick margins you see around some time course plots. Approximately [like so](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/).

Calculating this manually per time point would be an absolute pain, and it's a very common (and imho useful) plotting gimmick - there *has* to be something for this!

But there'S no example in the maltplotlib gallery. Could you help me out?

Comment: Are you asking about how to find the standard error, or to plot it?  There's not going to be any one method that can calculate the standard error for a time series.  Once you have it, there are several ways to plot it.

Comment: I was thinking maybe if I just give it a 2d array there'S a function that can do the adequate magick. But ok, if I have my data in a multiindexed pandas dataframe with participant ID as the first index and time point as a second, do you know any quick way to sem() that?

Comment: ok, I finally got my SEMs - any suggestions on pretty and simple ways to plot them?

Comment: If you have SEM as an array the same shape as your time series, try `plt.fill_between(t, y+sem/2, y-sem/2, alpha=0.5)` then `plt.plot(t, y)` to plot the actual time series over a band of width sem.